# Sign in using Google account in Android

Tags: java, android, google-account

Is there beautiful way to let user to sign in with it's GMail account?
without typing his email, password and so on

Comment: ***without typing his email, password and so on*** then what kind of login it is?

Comment: 1 step: User pushes button "Sign in with Google account", 2 step Android ask user, if he wants to let application access his account, 3 step - User press "Yes", 4 step application gets google account data to sign in

Comment: you have to ask for email and password at least for first time and then save it somewhere and when ever you hits sign in button use that information to login but this will be limited to one user only cause without any kind of information you can not distinguish users.

Comment: @harry-joy: I've seen this type of authentication that I described in previous comment. But I cannt find way to implement it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean with an account that is stored on the phone already, and you are accessing a Google service that requires a token rather than username/password you could look at the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)